# Start Linphone MediaStreamer2 Audio & Video Stream Together

Tags: android, c, voip, linphone, linphone-sdk

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/mediastreamer2
https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android

Using only mediastreamer2 library I am able to start a audio call with remote ip and port given and calling audiostream.c respective methods.

i then needed to start video call as well. so initialised videostream.c and 
using its respective methods and providing it with surfaces to render remote and local camera feed. i am able to start video stream successfully with remote port and ip given.

But problem is when i start both streams together. sound stops and video streaming also gets stop. only local camera feed works.

So i have a one magical method that do all this for me. if i comment the video part of it. audio call works fine and if comment the audio part, video call works fine. but when i start both. No sound No Streaming.
but we get AudioStream started successfully and VideoStream started successfully log.

Can someone with linphone experience help as figuring the correct sequence of methods? or what are we doing wrong. Here is our method.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL  Java_com_myapp_services_LinPhoneMSEngine_LinPhoneMSVE_1AudioStreamStartFull
(JNIEnv *env, jclass self, jstring remote_ip, jint remote_port, jint localport, jint payloadindex, jboolean isLowEnd)
{
int bRetVal = 0;
MSVideoSize size = {320, 240};
char rtcp_tool[128]={0};
int ret;
//jboolean copy;
char cname[128]={0};
const char *cremote_ip;

ortp_warning("Audio Stream Start Full");
LOGD("Audio Stream Start Full");

cremote_ip = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, remote_ip, NULL);
ortp_warning("Cremote_ip= %s", cremote_ip);
LOGD("Cremote_ip= %s", cremote_ip);

//  ms_filter_enable_statistics(TRUE);

veData->queue = ortp_ev_queue_new();
veData->soundCard = NULL;

set_playback_device();


ortp_warning("sound: playback_dev_id: %s", ms_snd_card_get_string_id(veData->soundCard));
LOGD("sound: playback_dev_id: %s", ms_snd_card_get_string_id(veData->soundCard));

veData->CaptureCard = NULL;
set_capture_device();

ortp_warning("sound: capture_dev_id: %s", ms_snd_card_get_string_id(veData->CaptureCard));
LOGD("sound: capture_dev_id: %s", ms_snd_card_get_string_id(veData->CaptureCard));


veData->audioStream = audio_stream_new(msFactory ,localport, localport + 1, false);

audio_stream_enable_adaptive_bitrate_control(veData->audioStream, true);
audio_stream_enable_adaptive_jittcomp(veData->audioStream, true);
rtp_session_set_jitter_compensation(veData->audioStream->ms.sessions.rtp_session, 50);

rtp_session_enable_rtcp_mux(veData->audioStream->ms.sessions.rtp_session, true);
ret=AUDIO_STREAM_FEATURE_VOL_SND | \
            AUDIO_STREAM_FEATURE_VOL_RCV;

if (!isLowEnd)
{
    ret = ret | AUDIO_STREAM_FEATURE_EC | AUDIO_STREAM_FEATURE_EQUALIZER | AUDIO_STREAM_FEATURE_DTMF | AUDIO_STREAM_FEATURE_DTMF_ECHO;
    audio_stream_set_features(veData->audioStream, ret);

    ortp_warning("Setting Echo Canceller params");
    LOGD("Setting Echo Canceller params");

    rtp_session_enable_jitter_buffer(veData->audioStream->ms.sessions.rtp_session, TRUE);

    audio_stream_set_echo_canceller_params(veData->audioStream, 60, 0, 128);

    audio_stream_enable_gain_control(veData->audioStream, true);
    audio_stream_enable_automatic_gain_control(veData->audioStream, true);

}
else
{
    audio_stream_set_features(veData->audioStream, ret);

    ortp_warning("No Echo Canceller params!!");
    LOGD("No Echo Canceller params!!");
    rtp_session_enable_jitter_buffer(veData->audioStream->ms.sessions.rtp_session, FALSE);

}

if( veData->audioStream == NULL){
    ortp_warning("AudioStream is Null");
    LOGD("AudioStream is Null");
    bRetVal = -1;
    return -1;
}

audio_stream_play_received_dtmfs(veData->audioStream, true);


snprintf(rtcp_tool,sizeof(rtcp_tool)-1,"%s-%s","Android","2.8.0");

snprintf(cname,sizeof(cname)-1,"%s-%d", cremote_ip, remote_port);
ortp_warning("cname value: %s",cname);
LOGD("cname value: %s",cname);
audio_stream_prepare_sound(veData->audioStream, veData->soundCard, veData->CaptureCard);

if(0== audio_stream_start_full(veData->audioStream,veData->prof, cremote_ip, remote_port, cremote_ip, remote_port + 1, 114, 50,NULL,NULL,veData->soundCard,veData->CaptureCard, !isLowEnd))
{
    veData->rtpSession = veData->audioStream->ms.sessions.rtp_session;
    ortp_warning("AudioStreamStartFull Success");
    post_audio_config(veData->audioStream);
    audio_stream_set_rtcp_information(veData->audioStream, cname, rtcp_tool);
}
else
{
    ortp_warning("AudioStream start failed");
    bRetVal = -1;
}

// init video stream
veData->videoStream = video_stream_new(msFactory, localport,localport+1,false);

video_stream_enable_adaptive_bitrate_control(veData->videoStream, true);
video_stream_enable_adaptive_jittcomp(veData->videoStream, true);
rtp_session_enable_rtcp_mux(veData->videoStream->ms.sessions.rtp_session, true);

video_stream_use_video_preset(veData->videoStream, "custom");
video_stream_set_sent_video_size(veData->videoStream, size);
video_stream_set_preview_size(veData->videoStream, size);
video_stream_enable_self_view(veData->videoStream, TRUE);

ortp_message("Video Stream : [%p] & native window id : [%p]",veData->videoStream, veData->native_window_id);
video_stream_set_native_window_id(veData->videoStream, veData->native_window_id);

ortp_message("Video Stream : [%p] & preview window id : [%p]",veData->videoStream, veData->native_preview_window_id);
video_stream_set_native_preview_window_id(veData->videoStream, veData->native_preview_window_id);

video_stream_use_preview_video_window(veData->videoStream, TRUE);
video_stream_set_device_rotation(veData->videoStream, 0);

video_stream_set_fps(veData->videoStream, 10.0);

// link audio with video
audio_stream_link_video(veData->audioStream, veData->videoStream);

ms_message("Setting webcam as %p", veData->msWebCam);
if(bRetVal != -1 && video_stream_start(veData->videoStream, veData->prof,
                      cremote_ip,
                      remote_port,
                      cremote_ip,
                      remote_port + 1,
                      101,
                      60,
                      veData->msWebCam) >=0 ) {

    ortp_warning("VideoStream started successfully");
    veData->rtpSession = veData->videoStream->ms.sessions.rtp_session;

    video_stream_set_rtcp_information(veData->videoStream, cname,rtcp_tool);
}
else
{
    ortp_warning("VideoStream start failed");
    bRetVal = -1;

}

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, remote_ip, cremote_ip);


return bRetVal;
}
```

Comment: i can provide a log file too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally with the help of @belledonne-communications.
we figured out we were sending both the streams on same port.

which is not possible. It needs to be sent on different ports. We corrected it and it worked.